Does the GTrXL Model from RLLIB supports dict/tuple observation?
im trying to use the AttentionNet GTrXL from RLLIB with a dictionary/tuple gym input. I found this example of complex inputs: Complex input nets. Now im not sure how to combine both properly.
I would like to feed a dictionary observation to the model which contains several Box spaces. Im a bit confused wether this needs to be customized, since some models already support complex spaces as i read.
I have already defined this dict observation space:
`observation_space = None
    values = {
        "left_arm_joint_position": gym.spaces.Box(low=self.robot.joint_limits_low, high=self.robots.joint_limits_high, shape=(7,)),
        "right_arm_joint_position": gym.spaces.Box(low=self.robot.joint_limits_low, high=self.robots.joint_limits_high, shape=(7,)),
        "left_arm_joint_velocity": gym.spaces.Box(low=-self.robot.joint_vel_limits, high=self.robot.joint_vel_limits, shape=(7,)),
        "right_arm_joint_velocity": gym.spaces.Box(low=-self.robot.joint_vel_limits, high=self.robot.joint_vel_limits, shape=(7,)),
        "left_arm_joint_torque": gym.spaces.Box(low=-self.robot.joint_torque_limits, high=self.robot.joint_torque_limits, shape=(7,)),
        "right_arm_joint_torque": gym.spaces.Box(low=-self.robot.joint_torque_limits, high=self.robot.joint_torque_limits, shape=(7,)),
        "depth_image": gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=255, shape=(self._render_height, self._render_width, 1)),
    }
    
    observation_space = gym.spaces.Dict(values)`  

But now im looking forward on how to feed this to the / a custom GTrXL model in RLLIB.

Were you able to make any progress on this?
